# How can i get smoother translation?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

In xaml i have defined my canvas as:

```
     <Canvas Name="GameCanvas">

            <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform x:Name="CanvasRenderTransform" />
            </Canvas.RenderTransform>
```

In c# I have defined the following where i store the initial scale and modify it as it get pinched:

```
private void GestureListener_DragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaGestureEventArgs e)
        {
            Point p = e.GetPosition(GameCanvas);

            CanvasRenderTransform.TranslateX = p.X - originDragPoint.X;
            CanvasRenderTransform.TranslateY = p.Y - originDragPoint.Y;
        }

        private void GestureListener_DragStarted(object sender, DragStartedGestureEventArgs e)
        {
            originDragPoint = e.GetPosition(GameCanvas);
        }
```

Anyone got a clue why it flickers when I move it and moves really poorly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution here is to use the DP CacheMode. This allows visual elements to be stored as bitmaps after the first render pass. We will have a better utilization of the GPU.

BitmapCaching should be used in scenarios where you are blending, transforming (translating, stretching, rotating).

Check this [link](http://techtwaddle.net/2011/03/10/windows-phone-7-translation-rotation-scaling-and-the-effect-of-bitmapcache-on-performance/) for an explanation and an awesome video.